# Deployment error. Build failed: src/index.js does not exist;

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

This drives me crazy - I'm getting the below error during firebase deploy (click the image to enlarge):

[image]

package.json

```
{
    "engines": {
        "node": "10"
    },
    "main": "src/index.js",
    ...
}
```

The index.js does exist under the src folder.

I tried to change the path in "main" to a fake path and then it fails before deployment which is expected.

However with the "main": "src/index.js" it actually starts to deploy and fails much later during the process as shown on the screenshot above.

What am I missing here?

I'm using firebase-tools v8.12.0

Comment: Please, share build steps and `firebase.json` (at least `functions` configuration).

Comment: @FrancescoColamonici sh*t.. I had "**/src/**" under "ignore" in the firebase.json, thanks a ton for the tip man, I've missed to look there (I was refactoring my code a bit and moved everything back to the "src" folder) - removing that line fixed it. If you post it as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it to mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check build steps and your `functions` configuration in `firebase.json`.